# How to use query .document using firebase ui

Tags: firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, firebaseui

I'm using this [Firebase-UI](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/firestore/README.md#querying)

I have Users (collection), uid (document), and array for image url.

[This is my Firebase schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TN8AQ.jpg)

How to use document query so I can get specific user and get `imageUrl`?

```
Query query = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
    .collection("users")
    .document(auth.currentUser!!.uid)
```

Error:

> None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied.
>   setQuery(Query, (snapshot: DocumentSnapshot) → Profile) defined in com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder
>   setQuery(Query, SnapshotParser) defined in com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder
>   setQuery(Query, Class) defined in com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder

this works, but i just want to know if i can use .document

```
val query = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
        .collection("users")
        .whereEqualTo(FieldPath.documentId(), auth.currentUser!!.uid)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to use the following line of code:

```
Query query = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
    .collection("users")
    .document(auth.currentUser!!.uid)
```

Once because this is not the way you are declaring variables in Kotlin. And second because when calling `document()` function on a [CollectionReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/CollectionReference) object it returns a [DocumentRefence](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentReference) object and not a [Query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/Query.html) object.

So you can simply use:

```
val document = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
    .collection("users")
    .document(auth.currentUser!!.uid)
```

And the `document` object will now of type `DocumentReference`.

Comment: Can i set it using .setQuery? it doesn't accept document
`val options = FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Profile>()
            .setQuery(query, Profile::class.java)
            .build()`

Comment: No, you cannot pass the document object to the set setQuery function because the type is DocumentRefence and not Query. You cannot use Firebase-UI that way. Only a Query object or a CollectionReference are accepted and this because CollectionReference extends Query.

Comment: yeah but i thought there is .setDocument or something, i guess i can only use whereEqualTo. thanks